# Type hinting a custom class that can be iterated in custom class collection

Tags: python, class, annotations, type-hinting

I have a custom class collection with custom classes, but typehints wont work for me this way

```
foo = CustomClass("abc")
bar = CustomClass("cba")

collection = CustomClassCollection([foo, bar])

for item in collection:
    item.<typehints here won't show up>
```

how can i workaround here to show type hints for iterated item?

here's CustomClassCollection iter method:

```
def __iter__(self) -> CustomClass:
    return next(self)
```

implementation of CustomClassCollection:

```
class CustomClassCollection(KeyIndexedCollection, JsonSerializable):
    def __init__(self, items: Optional[List[CustomClass]] = None):
        super().__init__(items)
        self._collection = {}
        self._add_items_impl(self._collection, take_with_default(items, []))

    def _add_items_impl(self, dst_collection, items):
        for item in items:
            self._add_impl(dst_collection, item)

    def add(self, item: CustomClass) -> CustomClassCollection:
        return self.clone(items=[*self.items(), item])

    def add_items(self, items: List[CustomClass]) -> CustomClassCollection:
        return self.clone(items=[*self.items(), *items])

    def get(self, key: str, default: Optional[Any] = None) -> ObjClass:
        return self._collection.get(key, default)

    def __next__(self) -> CustomClass:
        yield from self._collection.values()

    def __iter__(self) -> CustomClass:
        return next(self)

    def items(self) -> List[CustomClass]:
        return list(self._collection.values())
```

Implementation of CustomClass:

```
class CustomClass(KeyObject, JsonSerializable):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name

    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name
```

Comment: Add type annotations to the class's `__iter__` method?

Comment: @Aran-Fey i've updated question with `__iter__` method

Comment: Can you share your CustomClass and CustomClassCollection implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `__iter__` to:

```
def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[CustomClass]:
    return next(self)
```

Did the job